# Mobile tracking on google maps android app

Tags: android, google-maps, parse-platform

I am developing and android app where one user can track location of other user in real time over google maps. I am using Parse for backend to store lat long of the user to be tracked. I am able to successfully store realtime lat long when it changes, but problem is how can I query from parse every second or when data changes in parse and display on google map.

Example: We have 2 users : user1 and user2 
- user1 is storing its location continuously in Parse.
- user2 is tracking location of user1 based on lat long from parse DB and displays on the user2 map.

NOTE :its same like in UBER we can track cars movement.

User1 location saved to Parse.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location Detected*****************");
    mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));

    // Update Map
    //updateCamera();
    updatePolyline();
    service.saveGeoPoints(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

}
```

User2 shows user1's location on map

```
public ParseObject[] getGeoPoints(String followUser){
    final ParseObject[] result = new ParseObject[10];
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("LatLong");
    query.whereEqualTo("userId", followUser);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
                Iterator itr = objects.iterator();
                int count =0;
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    result[count++] = (ParseObject) itr.next();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

How to make it like listner

Please help me how to do achieve this. Please let me know if you have any other better solution. Thanks

Comment: show some code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understend if your problem is getting the person location or making it continuously but I assume your problem is making it update. Try looking into AsyncTank functions, you'll need to make one in order to make it update every second without crashing the app.

Take a look in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I am using Parse as backend and storing all Lat Long in there. So my problem is how I can i request location feed from Parse every second. Is there anything like that available? Is it good to request every second ?

Answer (score 0):

use mlocmanager

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

## requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)

```
 mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

this will send feed every second,you can give distance too

Comment: My problem is I am using Parse as backend and storing all Lat Long in there. So How I can i request location feed from Parse every second. Is there anything like that available? Is it good to request every second ?

Comment: save your location feed using above code to parse. then get it from parse.